# Peekable content is None after refactor the code

Tags: rust, ref, reference-counting, refcell

I have this method:

```
fn parse_http_request_headers<'b>(sp: &'b mut std::str::Split<&str>) -> HashMap<String, String> {
        let mut headers: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
        let mut iter = sp.peekable();

        while iter.peek() != None {
            let next = iter.next();
            if let Some(value_to_parse) = next {
                let parts = value_to_parse.split(": ").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
                let key = parts.get(0);
                if parts.len() == 2 {
                    headers.insert(
                        (*key.expect(&format!("Error getting the header definition: {:?}", &key)))
                            .to_string(), 
                        (*parts.get(1)
                            .expect(&format!("Error getting the header value from: {:?}", &parts)))
                            .to_string()
                    );
                }
            } else { iter.next(); }
        }

        headers
    }
```

that I refactored for curiosity about playing with the `Interior mutability pattern`, to try to solve some doubts about struct's fields that contains references.
But, ok, let's go with the code:

```
fn parse_http_request_headers<'b>(sp: Rc<RefCell<&'b mut std::str::Split<&str>>>) -> HashMap<String, String> {
        
        let mut headers: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
        let mut borrow = sp.borrow_mut();  // let binding
        
        let mut iter = borrow.peekable();
        
        while iter.peek() != None {
            
            let next = iter.next();
            if let Some(value_to_parse) = next {
                let parts = value_to_parse.split(": ").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
                let key = parts.get(0);
                if parts.len() == 2 {
                    headers.insert(
                        (*key.expect(&format!("Error getting the header definition: {:?}", &key)))
                            .to_string(), 
                        (*parts.get(1)
                            .expect(&format!("Error getting the header value from: {:?}", &parts)))
                            .to_string()
                    );
                }
            } else { iter.next(); }
        }
        headers
    }
```

But, for my surprise, there's no iterations over the peekable `peeked: None`.

Why is causing this?

The first version works perfect parsing the http headers, this is the output:

```
HttpRequest { verb: GET, uri: Uri { uri: "/" }, http_version: V1_1, headers: {"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", "Connection": "keep-alive", "DNT": "1", "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", "Host": "127.0.0.1:7878", "Sec-GPC": "1", "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document"}, body: None }
```

The calling code:

```
let rc: Rc<RefCell<&mut Split<&str>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(sp));
        
let (verb, uri, version) = Self::parse_verb_uri_version(Rc::clone(&rc));
let body = Self::parse_http_request_body(Rc::clone(&rc).borrow_mut().last().unwrap());
let headers = Self::parse_http_request_headers(Rc::clone(&rc));
```

where `sp`:
`sp: &'a mut Split<&'a str>`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output of both versions?

Comment: Did you include the full code sample? Why make the iterator peekable if the peeked value is never acted upon? At the moment, the usage of the iterator is equivalent to just putting it in a for loop.

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: @Locke the usage of the iterator is irrelevant on the question.

Comment: Aaah, the issue was pretty obvious.  The call on `.last()` consumes the iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`.last()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.last) in the proceeding line which will consume all elements from the iterator leaving nothing behind to iterate in `parse_http_request_headers()`.

Comment: BTW, there's a way to pick the last element without consuming the elements?

Comment: @AlexVergara You are unable to do that. While some types allow you to jump to the end, `Split` does not have this functionality.

Comment: @AlexVergara You can use `next_back()` but this will consume the last item.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `next_back()` is unavailable since `Split<&str>` is not double-ended. See [DoubleEndedSearcher examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.DoubleEndedSearcher.html#examples) for rationale.

Comment: Ah, right, only `char` is.

Comment: yup, i tried the transformation to a `DoubleEndedIterator` but I am not able to